# How to revise a list based upon one of its value

Tags: python, iteration

Suppose I have a list

```py
height_per_row = [[(200, 3), (100, 1), (200, 2)], [(200, 4), (25, 1), (0, 0)]]
```

In the inner list I divide the first value by the second value and it returns their ratio, out of these ratios the maximum of the ratios will decide the revision of the inner list.

expected result

```py
[[(300, 3), (100, 1), (200, 2)], [(200, 4), (50, 1), (0, 0)]]
```

I did it like this, but it required me to iterate over the list two times.

```py
for row in height_per_row:
    # iteration 1
    principal_height_ratio = max(height / (span or 1) for height, span in row)
    # iteration 2
    for i, (height, span) in enumerate(row):
        if height / (span or 1) < principal_height_ratio:
            row[i] = (span * principal_height_ratio, span)
```

Is there a way to do it without iterating over the same list twice?

Comment: Could you explain how you go from (200, 3) to (300, 3)? Is it because 100/1 (and 200/2) equals 100, while 200/3 < 100; and then 3 * 100 = 300?

Comment: @9769953 for the first yes, also no I don't want to add dependencies to my project because I am not the owner of the project

Comment: You have a couple of errors in there: `enumerate(height_per_row)` should be `enumerate(row)` and `principal_height_ration ` has a trailing `n` that should not be there

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's possible to avoid the two iterations. It's possible to make the same code in two lines using list comprehensions (which I guess are "pythonic"), but it won't operate in-place like your code and probably will be a little slower.

Answer (score -1):

You can use numpy with one iteration , but there will be a warning of the true_divide with 0.

```
import numpy as np

height_per_row = [[(200, 3), (100, 1), (200, 2)], [(200, 4), (25, 1), (0, 0)]]

height_per_row_new = []
for row in height_per_row:
    # iteration 1
    array_row = np.array(row)
    
    devide_result = array_row[:, 0] / (array_row[:, 1])
    
    devide_result[~np.isfinite(devide_result)] = 0
    
    principal_height_ratio = np.max(devide_result)
    row_temp = np.copy(array_row)
    row_temp[:, 0] = array_row[:, 1] * principal_height_ratio
    height_per_row_new.append(list(map(tuple, row_temp)))
```

Comment: `devide_result = array_row[:, 0] / (array_row[:, 1])` and `row_temp[:, 0] = array_row[:, 1] * principal_height_ratio` are two iterations together. `~np.isfinite(devide_result)` adds a third iteration, `np.max(devide_result)` a fourth, `np.copy(array_row)` a fifth.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think the questioner wants to use just one `for` loop to solve the problem. But in your answer you have used two, but unfortunately, you have deleted your answer.

Comment: The OP mentions avoiding to iterate multiple times over the list: "without iterating over the same list twice". Since NumPy iterates over the array under the hood, there are multiple (implicit) iterations in your code. (The OP also mentions in a comment they want to avoid NumPy (as "dependencies").)